# Fetching a POST request in Meteor via a notification url

Tags: javascript, post, meteor, cloudinary

This is something I have no experience with.

On the admin page I'm building it's possible to upload a picture to a service called Cloudinary to have its background removed, a process that takes up to 24 hours, upon which they send a POST request to some url that I send along with the request.

This format doesn't lend itself very well to experimenting, so I need some help.

This is how the picture is uploaded and the request sent:

```
Cloudinary.upload(image, {
    folder: "cutouts",
    type: "upload",
    notification_url: "someurl.com"
    background_removal: "remove_the_background"
}, function(error, result) {
       if (!error)
           console.dir(result)
   }
})
```

**Question**: what do I set as the `notification_url`? Even if it's somewhere on my site, do I need to deploy it before I can check that the code works?

Here's an example of what they will send back, according to their docs:

```
{ 
  "notification_type": "info",
  "info_kind": "remove_the_background",
  "info_status": "complete",
  "public_id": "wood_chair",
  "uploaded_at": "2014-10-26T11:35:22Z",
  "version": 1414316122,
  "url": 
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1393688588/wood_chair.jpg",
  "secure_url":
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1393688588/wood_chair.jpg",
  "etag": "a56e9e88c2add15cac1775c1f687bf73"
}
```

So, specifically I need access to the `info_status` and the `url`.

Problem is, I can't experiment and I have *no* idea how to approach this problem since I have no experience with this stuff at all.

Here are their docs if it's any help: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/remove_the_background_image_editing_addon

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server side, set up a route (assuming you are using iron-router) to handle the post from cloudinary:

```
Router.route('/api/cloudinary', { where: 'server' })
    .post(function() {
        var body = this.request.body; // get the body out of the response
        var url = body.url; // based on the JSON you showed
        this.response.statusCode = 200; // set the status code to be returned to cloudinary
        this.response.end(); // send response
    }
);
```

You can change `/api/cloudinary/` to whatever you want. If your site was `http://www.example.com`, then the cloudinary notification url would be:

```
http://www.example.com/api/cloudinary
```

Comment: If you don't want to add iron:router (for example, because you are already using flow-router), you can also use meteorhacks:picker to set up a server side  route.  The syntax is a little different but the concept is same as this.

Comment: Great stuff. I installed a Chrome app to send dummy requests so I can emulate the real situation and experiment a bit. Things are looking good!

Comment: You can also use 3rd party tools such as http://requestb.in/ in order to experiment prior to setting up the endpoint on your application.